# Upcasting F# record created through reflection

Tags: reflection, f#, record

I've been messing about with F# and it's Reflection, trying to create a Record type object dynamically from within F#, I got most of it working (as you can see below) but one thing - the record I create through reflection has type "obj" instead the one it should ("Person") and I can't seem to be able to upcast it in any way.

```
#light

type Person = {
    Name:string;
    Age:int;
}

let example = {Name = "Fredrik"; Age = 23;}
// example has type Person = {Name = "Fredrik"; Age = 23;}

let creator = Reflection.FSharpValue.PrecomputeRecordConstructor(example.GetType(), 
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)

let reflected = creator [| ("thr" :> obj); (23 :> obj) |]
// here reflected will have the type obj = {Name = "thr"; Age = 23;}

// Function that changes the name of a Person record
let changeName (x:Person) (name:string) = 
    { x with Name = name }

// Works with "example" which is has type "Person"
changeName example "Johan"

// But not with "reflected" since it has type "obj"
changeName reflected "Jack" // Error "This expression has type obj but is here used with type Person. "

// But casting reflected to Person doesn't work either
(reflected :> Person) // Type constraint mismatch. The type   obj is not compatible with 
                      // type  Person. The type 'obj' is not compatible with the type 'Person'. 
                      // C:\Users\thr\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\
                      // Reflection\Reflection\Script.fsx   34  2   Reflection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the other cast operator (as you're casting the other way this time)

So changeName (reflected **:?>** Person) "Jack"

Comment: What's the difference between the :> and :?> operator?

Comment: The best explanation is probably here: 
http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/fsharp_v1.1.12/FSharp-1.1.12.3/manual/import-interop.html#Upcasts

But the basics is that if you're going from a class to its parent (i.e. anything to obj) you use :>. But if you're going the other way you use :?>...

Comment: ":>" is an upcast, converting an object to a parent type -- its always safe, and upcasting errors can be caught by the compiler. ":?>" is a downcast, convert an object to a descendant type -- downcasts are never safe since downcast errors always result in runtime exceptions.